# How to merge two regular expression

Tags: regex

How can I merge this two regular expression:

```
\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*
^{4,}$
```

So, that result match both?

Comment: To merge multiple expressions you can use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) but `^{4,}$` doesn't make sense and would fail off the start because their is no preceding token that is quantifiable. Perhaps rephrase your question clearly.

Comment: What does `^{4,}$` do?

Comment: what do you mean by merging?

Comment: Yes - do you mean "Accept results that match the first one, and also results that match the second one (but not necessarily both at once)", or "Accept only results that match both expressions (and not one or the other)"?

Comment: seems like you want like this `^(?=.{4,})\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*`

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I need.
Write it as answer that I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Avinash Raj, it's what I need:

```
^(?=.{4,})\w*[A-Za-z_]+\w*
```